# GitHub - Self Fork Repository Within Organization

Tags: github, repository, fork, organization

I have private github account who is the owner of a private organization. In my organization I have a repository with my project in it. I have 2 programmers who I want to get in on my project but I don't want them to have access to the master repository, so I want to fork that repository, inside of my organization (a self fork if you will) and give my 2 new programmers access to the fork, but not the master.

This should be one of the simplest task to accomplish on github, however I can't find how to do it.

See, I'm not looking for how to give access rights and what not, I already know that, I just want to make a fork of the master repo that they can have access to. Is that too much to ask? because there doesn't seem to be a way to do is in GitHub.

Basically, is there a way to fork your own repo, inside of an organization, in a simple practical way?

Comment: Forking within an organization is [now (June 2022) possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72780662/6309).

Answer (score 1):

You can't fork a repo within the same organisation or user account. What you can do is manually create the new repository via GitHub; add your new repo as a remote to your existing clone; and then push to the new repo (https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/). They won't be linked in any way and you'll only end up with a 'fork' of the branches you push but you can use this to create as many new 'forks' as you want.