# fork repo from personal account into organisation acount

Tags: github

I developed a project on my personal github account.
I'm a member (not owner) of an organisation and would like to fork my project in the organisational account, such that the organisation can help maintain it in the future. 
How is this done best?

As far as I understood, when I [transfer](https://help.github.com/en/articles/transferring-a-repository#transferring-a-repository-owned-by-your-personal-account) or perform an [import](https://github.com/new/import) into the organisation account from my personal repo, I loose the project in my account which I don't want.

I'm sorry in case this is a "stupid" question - I'm pretty new to git and github...

Comment: Forking within an organization is [now (June 2022) possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72780662/6309).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers.

According to the github support team:

> Importing is intended to bring code from outside GitHub into GitHub, so that wouldn't be suitable.

and

> Transferring would indeed mean you no longer had the repository on your account.

The solution for me was:

1. requested owner priviledges for the organisation (in case that would not be possible, ask an owner to perform the following steps)
2. went to the repository which I wanted to fork (In my case, this was on my personal profile and I was logged in with my personal account. I don't have any login informations for the organisation account)
3. pressed `fork` and there was a pop-up, asking for where to fork this repo
4. selected the organisation

I hope to help others in the future with this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Any reason not to transfer it, then fork it again back to your account?

That way you can still raise pull requests from your person fork back to the main one.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to `import` without loosing the project in your personal account.
This is what IMO makes the difference between `transfer` and `import`.
Be sure to login with your organizational account, if you have two separate accounts